# Solr Sunspot - How to boost belongs_to association on searchable with Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, solr, sunspot

I'm using Sunspot Solr for indexing and searching in our Ruby on Rails application with MongoDB database (Mongo mapper)

I have class Article which belongs_to User . I index my object User with Sunspot SOLR. It looks like this:

```
    class Article
    include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
    include MongoMapper::Document
    include Sunspot::Mongo
    ...


    key :title, String
    key :introduction, String
    key :cover, String
    ...

    belongs_to :user
    ...

    searchable do
      text :title, :boost => 5
      text :user do
        user.username if user
      end
      string(:category)
      boolean(:published)
    end
```

I am able to search on the `user.username` field of the Top model successfully but the when I boost this field for exemple like :

```
  text :user, :boost => 10  do
    user.username if user
  end
```

It's not working, Sunspot ignore the boost totally (the title field works well)

Is it a syntax error ?

Please help !

Thanks.